# How can I inspect app-specific CloudKit data, or access data not accessible in iTunes App?

Tags: ios, iphone, icloud, cloudkit, privacy

iOS has a method to expose some of the app data to the end user via iTunes.

In addition, an application can store information in CloudKit that is only accessible to the app itself (and presumably not the app author, nor the end user themselves)

- How can I inspect the data of a 3rd party app which uploads into my personal iCloud account?
- How can I inspect the data of a 3rd party app which stores data in the app container (the "other" allocation in the storage view) on my local device

Edit -

So I'm wanting to see all data not just when `UIFileSharingEnabled` is enabled.

I also want to inspect my personal CKData (CKRecord) that would be added into my account.  In theory, and if I had the developer's permission, I would navigate to https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard/ and inspect it there.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what kind of file you want to see.

> How can I inspect the data of a 3rd party app which uploads into my
>   personal iCloud account?

In general, if you want to see what an app stores in iCloud, just open iCloud Drive tab (only macOS):
[image: iCloud Drive]

> How can I inspect the data of a 3rd party app which stores data in the app container (the "other" allocation in the storage view) on my local device

To access data stored locally, one of the best app is iExplorer (paid): https://macroplant.com/iexplorer

Comment: Not all data exposed to iCloud is visible here.

Comment: This is only for *documents* stored in Cloud Drive. The OP (me too) would like to access cloudkit data - "structured app and user data in iCloud" referenced here -  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987